# Proving a tricky set of inequalities with double induction

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-writing, induction

Here's what I need to prove:

$$\frac{n^k}{k^k} \le {n \choose k} \le \frac{n^k}{k!} $$

I figure this calls for a proof by induction. I feel like I have to do a proof by induction on both n and k. I started with a base case where both are 0. But the induction part is where I get stuck.

I started with assuming the statement held true for $n-1$ and I've so far reasoned that 
$${n \choose k}-{n-1 \choose k-1} \le \frac{(n-1)^k}{k!} \le \frac{n^k}{k!}$$ with pascal's identity, but I'm really stuck on how to get to the final inequality. With induction on k I'm completley lost!!

Comment: Algebraic manipulation is fine! I figured that it would have to be induction because we've focused on it in class but truth be told I'd much rather use algebra. What do you mean by the second one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving the inequality $\frac{n^k}{k^k}\leq\binom{n}{k}\leq\frac{n^k}{k!}$ involving binomial coefficient.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1509361/proving-the-inequality-fracnkkk-leq-binomnk-leq-fracnkk-invol) – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bn%5Ek%7D%7Bk%5Ek%7D%20%5Cle%20%7Bn%20%5Cchoose%20k%7D%20%5Cle%20%5Cfrac%7Bn%5Ek%7D%7Bk!%7D%24&p=1)

Answer (score 3):

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)}{k!}\le\frac{n^k}{k!}$$

$$\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n}{k}\cdots\frac{n-k+1}{1}\ge\left(\frac{n}{k}\right)^k$$

(You still need to prove these smaller steps by induction:)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The upper bound is straight forward.

You can calculate the lower bound directly as follows:

Note that for $0 <  k \leq n$ you have for $i = 0,\ldots , k-1$

- $1-\frac{i}{k} \leq 1-\frac{i}{n}$

It follows
$$\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \left( 1-\frac{i}{k}\right) \leq \prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \left( 1-\frac{i}{n}\right)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{k^k}\underbrace{\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \left( k-i \right) }_{=k!}\leq \frac{1}{n^k}\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \left( n-i \right)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{n^k}{k^k} \leq \binom{n}{k}$$